# Problem to type a generic typescript structure

Tags: typescript

I would like to deal with data like

```
const stateTest  = {
  natures : {
    nature1: {
      amounts: {
        column1: 10,
        column2: 10,
      },
      natureDetails : {
        detail1 : {
          amounts: {
            column1: 10,
            column2: 10,
          },
          descriptionShown: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where the list of columns (here column1,column2) is a parameter

so I declared the following types and interfaces

```
type State<T extends GenericColumnList> = T & {
  natures: naturesSet<T>
}
type GenericColumnList = Record<string, number>
type naturesSet<T extends GenericColumnList> = Partial<Record<string, RowNature<T>>>
export interface RowNature<T extends GenericColumnList> {
  natureDetails: NatureDetailsSet<T>
  amounts: T
}
type NatureDetailsSet<T> = Partial<Record<string, RowDetailNature<T>>>
export interface RowDetailNature<T> {
  amounts: T
  descriptionShown: boolean
}
```

but when I try to pass the following columnList interface as parameter to State

```
export interface MyColumns  {
  column1?: number
  column2?: number
}
```

that is :

```
const stateTest: State<MyColumns>  = {
  natures : {
    nature1: {
      amounts: {
        column1: 10,
        column2: 10,
      },
      natureDetails : {
        detail1 : {
          montants: {
            column1: 10,
            column2: 10,
          },
          descriptionShown: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The typescript compiler complains that

'The type MyColumns doesn't comply with Record<string, number> ' and I do not understand why.

Comment: Presumably `montants` is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Record<string, number>` has a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).  The *`interface`* `MyColumns` does *not* have an index signature, and so the types are not compatible.

---

There is such a concept as an [*implicit* index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures), in which types without an explicit index signature are seen as compatible with an indexable type as long as all the known properties conform to the index signature... but *this does not apply to types declared as an `interface`*; it only works with anonymous types (or `type` aliases of such anonymous types).  There is an open issue in GitHub, [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), discussing this.  It turns out that, for now anyway, this behavior is [by design](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024).

So one way to deal with this is to make `MyColumns` a type alias of an anonymous type instead of any interface, like this:

```
export type MyColumns = {
  column1?: number
  column2?: number
}
```

Then, you will need to include `undefined` in the domain of `GenericColumnList` because the type of `MyColumns['column1']` is `number | undefined` and not just `number` (assuming we are using the recommended `--strict` compiler options including [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks)):

```
type GenericColumnList = Record<string, number | undefined>
```

And then your assignment works:

```
const stateTest: State<MyColumns> = {
  natures: {
    nature1: {
      amounts: {
        column1: 10,
        column2: 10,
      },
      natureDetails: {
        detail1: {
          amounts: {
            column1: 10,
            column2: 10,
          },
          descriptionShown: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}; // okay
```

---

Assuming we don't want to require people use non-`interface` types for `T`, we could instead make `GenericColumnList` itself generic in `T` so that instead of an index signature it just has the same keys as `T`:

```
type GenericColumnList<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: number }
```

Here we've made the properties optional (`?`) for the same reason as adding `| undefined` earlier: to make optional/missing keys compatible in the presence of `--strictNullChecks`.

This requires some sprinkling of `<T>` around your code:

```
type State<T extends GenericColumnList<T>> = T & {
  natures: NaturesSet<T>
}
type NaturesSet<T extends GenericColumnList<T>> = Partial<Record<string, RowNature<T>>>
export interface RowNature<T extends GenericColumnList<T>> {
  natureDetails: NatureDetailsSet<T>
  amounts: T
}
```

and again, your assignment will work:

```
const stateTest: State<MyColumns> = {
  natures: {
    nature1: {
      amounts: {
        column1: 10,
        column2: 10,
      },
      natureDetails: {
        detail1: {
          amounts: {
            column1: 10,
            column2: 10,
          },
          descriptionShown: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}; // okay
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Y5q9skOSXg2aU3kysNPWkP6AAxVdtNqMaaOOfuDjtMbyTqe1i6-Y5tqeWOlXHA9xsrluU5cr4dd4A9idDlcj4Bj3sD09Nmc37Z0qAMvBMvAs9mcxwjY72-dIXwrgBt40kB3gANxICaSBKAA1iAaD0PQvj0KAkCwKMXxKCQdICGweAVPOpLOgEYpLEWUphKWdBIAA2gA0piSAwRAaBKEMqAALpxqG4b-pBppgCAzF9L0SiviyIA4EgQxFEgUDgMgdiECyHwBHmPDhLMIhiKRcSHkklFUXwZiNvOrxEjclFJiKXyTJZ0wRHMOkxGR+nrG0gIZFkkmgnKEKKlCNTjESbSoo6GL9IMOJjA0IWaZEzmLHpkoGR5pmTASS62ecmX2ciNI7lS1mfESuX-CSRhAt5OSyuCCpKkFsKLnFKIOgI6K9JF2IYeMmUtURDxgE8rZvA+9KMsyrIcvUXJILy-IgIK05tR1mJRRhhaHmIjbnkGIYJhG2znrG+1homy0WCm0rphQWbkLmnA8Jtkolik6XnFWQ7zpuN6FXuZ6Hse15-sd47A1Od4rvOuX-VOa7wj9f6DcNu4DUju1g7OSOdpKl4ntjkNI4+z7iVNn7SZJUC-vuQEdrTlj06BEFQbB8GId4QA)